# scrolling content in ncurses box

Tags: c, client-server, ncurses, curses

I have a window (created with `newwin` ) and create box (`box (WINDOW *, int, int)` ).

I read and write (on FD 0 and 1) under the box, and I get a `(char *)` from a socket, I wrote this tab in the box.

When I wrote 195 lines, I arrive on the end of the box.

How I can scroll the existing text, so that new text will print at the bottom?

Comment: I edited your question as much as I felt I understood what you meant, but it still needs work. Are you looking to create an always-scrolling interface, like a standard terminal emulator or `irssi` or something similar?

Comment: >Yeah exactly like irssi, a client-interface for irc.
And I'm sorry, am new on stack-overflow, my english is the worst ever see.
But you perfectly understant me ! (i should begin by that...)

Answer (score 3):

Use the `scrollok(WINDOW *win, bool bf);` function.

```
scrollok(win, TRUE);
```

From the man page:

> The scrollok option controls what happens when the cursor of a window is moved off the edge of the window or scrolling region, either as a
>   result  of  a newline action on the bottom line, or typing the last character of the last line.  If disabled, (bf is FALSE), the cursor is
>   left on the bottom line.  If enabled, (bf is TRUE), the window is scrolled up one line (Note that to get the physical scrolling effect  on
>   the terminal, it is also necessary to call idlok).

---

btw, I've written a very simple interface to an irc client in `c` using `ncurses` ([pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKpVp.png)), it is not complete, but you may want to peek for hints - [code](https://github.com/c00kiemon5ter/niii/blob/master/niii.c).

Comment: well i'll try scrollok.
> (i don't find a good reference for NCurse, have you got one ?)
thank you for you code, but is not very hard so i 'll not use it, But thank you !